# The acute angle between two plane

Tags: geometry

There are 2 planes.

plane 1: $2x+3y-4z=15$
plane 2: $x+y-4z=17$

How can I find the acute angle between 2 planes with those 2 equations?
thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the normal vectors to both planes, $\hat{n}_1$ and $\hat{n}_2$.

Next, find the angle between them by using the fact that $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = |u| |v| \cos{\theta}$.

How is the angle between the normal vectors related to the angle between the planes? ([This](http://www.netcomuk.co.uk/~jenolive/vecang3.jpg) picture may help)

Answer (score 0):

Angle between 2 planes is *defined* as the angle between their normals.

Comment: Well, not sure about *that* definition, @GTX OC. Over here, in high school 3-dimensional analytic geometry, it is defined in a very different, apparently, way: as two non-parallel planes $\;\pi_1,\pi_2\;$  *always* intersect in a straight line, call it $\;l\;$, the angle between $\;\pi_1,\pi_2\;$ is defined as follows: choose a point $\;O\;$ on $\;l\;$ and draw perpendiculars to $\;l\;$ at $\;O\;$ on $\;\pi_1,\pi_2\;$ . Now look at the plane determined by these perpendiculars and $\;O\;$. The angle between the perp's on this new plane is, by def., the angle between the planes.

Comment: What do you mean by "look at the place determined by these perpendiculars and O. "?

Comment: place =plane. it was edited before.